# How to get header of collection view in swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

How to get Header of collection view on DidSelectItemAtIndexPath for change text of header while select item.

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    let indexHeaderForSection = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: indexPath.section) // Get the indexPath of your header for your selected cell
    let header = collectionView.viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind(indexHeaderForSection)
}
```

Comment: Yes, i am getting Header on didSelectItemAtIndexPath but when scrolling collection view then after that selecting any item then it gives null value rather than header. Because section is out of queue i think.

Comment: It's normal, your header is not visible !

Comment: Do you have any idea, what is solution for that?

Comment: See: http://dativestudios.com/blog/2015/01/10/collection_view_sticky_headers/ That can help you !! Sticky header

Comment: Yes, it helps me. Thank you Jimmy James ..:)

Comment: Marks this answer as solution ;)

Comment: Sorry, i am not able to mark your answer because of less Reputation...:( Jimmy James

Comment: You saved me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS 9, you can use:

```
func supplementaryView(forElementKind elementKind: String, 
                 at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView?
```

to get a supplementary view by index path.

Check out [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618041-supplementaryview)